# Critical points of $g(x, y) = (x^2 + 1 - y^2)^2 + 4x^2y^2$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find all the critical points of Critical points of $g(x, y) = (x^2 + 1 - y^2)^2 + 4x^2y^2$, but I am having a little difficulty.

From my calculations, the only critical point is (0, 0), and it is a minimum.

But someone told me there are more then 1 critical points.
I have tried, but I cannot find any more than the one above.

If someone wouldnt mind lending a hand, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks
Corey

Comment: Look at the expression for $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ again, it can be zero at $y \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 4 y (x^2+y^2-1)$$
Set this to zero and check the solutions